# Resume visually separated

Tags: tcolorbox, cv

I'd like to separate professional experiences in my resume in such a way that each part are visually surrounded like this:

[image]

So :

1. is there a package to have header like this (date + Company + title)
2. and  after the items list, the tab with presentation
3. all of this represent each an experience that should be surrounded.

I've seen that tikz could do this but I'm not so used to do this.

Comment: Packages `tcolorbox`, `xcolor`/`colortbl` can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather quick solution is to use `tcolorbox`, `xcolor`, `colortbl` etc.

I did not tried to setup anything about the table and the adjustment at the top line. I also dropped some of the french words ;-) There is definitely some fine tuning to do afterwards, which depends on the particular content.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\MyResume}[3]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=1cm,width=\textwidth,colframe=orange,notitle,colback=white]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcrrrrrrrr}
#1 & #2   & & & & & & & &  #3 
\end{tabular}
\begin{itemize}
\item D\'evelopment
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\end{itemize}
\arrayrulecolor{cyan}
%\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{cyan} Langages & controleurs  & OS & Environnement & Drivers & Versionnement\tabularnewline
& & & & & \tabularnewline
& & & & & \tabularnewline

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
}%

\begin{document}
\MyResume{07/2001 -- 06/2005}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Europe Technologies}}}{\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{Ingenieur}}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not necessary to pack the code into a new command. As an improvement, the itemize list should be filled from outside, as well as the lower table.

**Alternate solution**

I changed the definition of the command `\MyResume`, the List and lower tabular content can be handed over as 4th and 5th argument. This work for not to complicated setups ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newrobustcmd*{\MyListResume}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item D\'evelopment
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\item Other line 
\end{itemize}
}%


\newrobustcmd*{\MyTabularResume}{%
\arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{cyan} Langages & controleurs  & OS & Environnement & Drivers & Versionnement\tabularnewline
& & & & & \tabularnewline
& & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%


\newrobustcmd*{\MyResume}[5]{%


\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=1cm,width=\textwidth,colframe=orange,notitle,colback=white,boxrule=1.5mm]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcrrrrrrrr}
#1 & #2   & & & & & & & &  #3 
\end{tabular}
#4%
#5%
\end{tcolorbox}
}%

\begin{document}

\MyResume{07/2001 -- 06/2005}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Europe Technologies}}}{\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{Ing\'enieur}}}{%
\MyListResume}{\MyTabularResume}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't imagine that it can be so close to my question. Thanks (+1 for French words ;) )

Comment: the MyListResume and MyTabularResume are used many times along the resume but with different contents (tab header included) maybe you know how to add them all along the resume ?

Comment: @user19433: I am not sure that I understand you correctly: Shall the `\MyListResume` and `\MyTabularResume` be changed for another resume or their content be directly included in the `resume` box?

Comment: I'd say in the same box. Both need to be repeated all along the same resume as they are included in the experience section but their textual contents will always be different, tab header included. Therefore, I thought of 3 macros <ul>: -07/2001 = 06/2005 + Europe Technologies  + Ingénieur -list items -tab header -tab cells contents. </ul>But maybe this should worth a new question for this ?

Comment: `\newrobustcmd{\MyResumeTimeRange}{07/2001--06/2005}`, `\newrobustcmd{\MyResumeTitle}{Europe Technologies}`, `\newrobustcmd{\MyResumeTopics}{Ingenieur etc}` ... for short, without colours. Insert them as 1st, 2nd, 3rd. argument to the `\MyResume` command. But changing the content may also change the spacings within the table.

Comment: You should use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and allow the `é` to be typed directly, I think it's better for kerning and stuff…

Comment: @Moriambar: Thanks, I wanted to revise this answer anyway, perhaps in a few hours -- it's one of my old answers