# Command calls with multiple parameters

Tags: macros, cv, parameters

I'd like to improve the latex code from a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173593/resume-visually-separated) by using it all along a resumé which I've reproduced below. The *MyFrame* command have to be called around 20 times but using different items text in a list and variable text in the tabular (col & rows) as well.

How is it possible to have this *MyFrame* command accepting call parameters with the items in the list and the ones in the tabular like :

```
{\MyFrame}(....)
{
 {listitems} 
  {Dévelopement}
  {Listitem2}
  {Listitem3}
 {tabular}
  {col1-row1 : Langages
   col2-row1 : controleurs
   Col1-Row1 : mytext1  
   Col2-Row2 : mytext2
  }
}
```

The main issue is that the lengths (list & tabular) are differents each time.

Original code :

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\definecolor{couleur_royalblue}{rgb}{0.254,0.411,0.882}

\newcommand{\MyFrame}[3]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=1cm,width=\textwidth,colframe=orange,notitle,colback=white]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lcrrrrrrrr}
#1 & #2 & & & & & & & &  #3 
\end{tabular}
    %this list is different each times
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Dévelopment
        \item Other line 
        \item Other line 
        \item Other line 
        \item Other line 
    \end{itemize}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\centering
   %this tabular is also different each times
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{couleur_royalblue} 
    Langages & controleurs  & OS & Environnement & Drivers & Versionnement\tabularnewline
    item11 & item2 & item3 & item4 & & \tabularnewline
    item21&item22& & & & \tabularnewline
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
\MyFrame{07/2001 -- 06/2005}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Europe Technologies}}}{\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{Ingenieur}}} \end{document}
```

Comment: Nice that you want to improve that answer of mine ;-) I suggest to use a key-value interface

Comment: Indeed it was so helpful that I want to make it better. I've found keyval  http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-keyval.html but not sure how is it better, even if I could use Python+Jinja2 scripts for this